# Applying visitor on syntax tree

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I am building a c interpreter. My AST uses the composite-pattern. To check semantics and perform actions, I wanna use the visitor-pattern. Now there's one problem. This is an grammar rule of the c-preprocessor: if-section = if-group [ elif-groups ] [ else-group ] endif-line. The visitor of if-section needs information about the child nodes, to know which groups have to be skipped. In the visitor-pattern, every "visit"-method returns void. So I can't get any information about these nodes (only with adding information to the nodes, but that's ugly ...). Are there any opportunities?

Comment: This will be easier to think about if you provide some code showing how you represent your AST.

Answer (score 2):

You've nailed the problem: you have to have additional information above and beyond the raw data that comprises the AST.

You can associate all of that extra information with just individual tree nodes: if you do that,  you'll end up building what is called an attributed tree.  In theory (and if you work at), you make this idea work completely.  Your visitor may have to inspect/update the information associated with not only the AST node it is visiting, but that of key children and parents.

In practice, it is useful to build auxiliary data structures (e.g., symbol tables) which can consulted by the visitor (and updated) as it walks the tree.  You end up with kind of degenerate attributed tree: you associate symbol table chunks with AST nodes that form scopes.

You've artificially constrained your visitor from returning any value; if you didn't do that, a child visitor could pass useful values to a parent visitor, enabling the parent to do less ad hoc reaching down the tree.

In your problem statement, you have not constrained your visitor from passing values down to children, so you can pass down useful values.  An extremely useful value to pass is the symbol table associated with the surrounding scope, so that children visitors don't have to climb back up the tree to find the scoping node, and the associated symbol table.

Comment: Yes thats great! A little another question: My composite which presents the AST has the base-class "node" which only holds a parent (type: nonterminal). terminal is one subclass of node and saves the position and value of the terminal. nonterminal is another subclass from node, which holds children (type: node). I don't create subclasses for all grammar-producations, but i save an enum-type instance in the nonterminal-node to know the node-type. If I create a nonterminal-node in my parser, I save a function-pointer to a function of my abstract visitor-class.

Comment: Later I can invoke the saved function-pointer on every derived visitor. What do you think about this type of pseudo-visitor-pattern?

Comment: @sknine: Its ok.  All that matters is that you can distinguish the AST nodes, access the values of varying terminals (e.g., "variables", "numbers", and "strings") and find parents and children.  I don't think you need your function-pointer; you already have an enum and your visitor(s) can simply use a case statemenent over the enum.  You may find that in fact you do several passes over the tree with different visitors ("build symbol table", "computer subxpression types", "generate code", at which point need 3 function pointers per node, or just the one enum used in 3 different visitors.

Comment: @skniine: The OO version of all this is to use a subclass instead of an enum for each of the node types, and introduce a method in each subclass for the pass/function pointer.  Your code will be prettier; you won't have the magic function pointer, and you won't have giant case statements.  You might be coding a non-OO language and think you can't do this, but in fact if you are using some of parser generator to build your tree, you should be able to coax it into generator class declarations for each node type (after all, you're getting enums and functions for each node type, somehow).

Comment: I have a hand-written recursive-descent parser. I just thought:"in the OO version, there will be a lot of subclasses for nothing, what I can also have in a non-OO version". If I read your comments, I think, that I don't get heavy problems without subclassing, right? Thank you for your help :).

Comment: @sknine: You can make it work just fine either way.  What matters is that you commit to one or the other and get on with.  And the end of your project, you'll have your own (self-validated) opinions about how nice your approach was, and you'll have more appreciation for the alternatives.  If you stick with the basics we've discussed above, you'll get through it; the alternatives are not make-or-break, just different (nicer?) style.